# openerp one2many issue with view

Tags: view, odoo

i am trying to create a module that stores multiple address of a partner. My issue is with view part, only city field is visible in form other fields are not visible, when "add an item" is clicked, the address fields are coming in random sequence like zipcode comes first, then street etc.

Kindly suggest how to proceed so that all fields are visible?

```
class extendcustomersaddress(orm.Model): 
  _name="res.partner" 
  _inherit = 'res.partner'
  _columns = 
   {
    'extraaddress':fields.one2many('seq.address','x_client_id','Address')
   }

 extendcustomersaddress()

class related_address(orm.Model): 
   _name="seq.address" 
   _columns = 
   { 
   'x_street' : fields.char('Street', size=170 ),
   'x_street1' : fields.char('Street1', size=170), 
   'x_city' : fields.char('City', size=170), 
   'x_state' : fields.char('state', size=170), 
   'x_zip' : fields.char('Zip code', size=10),
   'x_country' : fields.many2one('res.country', 'Country'), 
   'x_client_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'id',invisible=True) 
   }

related_address()

<openerp> 
   <data> 
     <record model="ir.ui.view" id="namelist_dailyupdate">
       <field name="name">res.partner.form</field> <field name="model">res.partner</field>

       <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
       <field name="type">form</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <notebook position="inside">
         <page string="Email">
            <separator string="Additional Emails" colspan="4"/>
             <tree name="abcd" editable="Bottom">
               <field name="extraaddress" />
             </tree>

         </page>
       </notebook>

     </field> 
   </record>

   </data> 
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<openerp> 
   <data> 
     <record model="ir.ui.view" id="namelist_dailyupdate">
     <field name="name">res.partner.form</field> <field name="model">res.partner</field>

     <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
     <field name="type">form</field>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
     <notebook position="inside">
     <page string="Email">
        <separator string="Additional Emails" colspan="4"/>
           <field name="extraaddress">
               <tree string="Extra Addresses" editable="bottom">
                   <field name="x_street"/>
                   <field name="x_street1"/>
                   <field name="x_city"/>
                   <field name="x_zip"/>
                   <field name="x_state"/>
                   <field name="x_country"/>
               </tree>
           </field>
         </page>
       </notebook>
     </field> 
   </record>
   </data> 
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a view for your model `seq.address` you can add inline view inside the `res.partner` view or separate view (both `tree` and `form`)

For exmaple refer `sale_view.xml` in sale order.